# glfw instantiate window position before/on create

Tags: c++, window, glfw

In glfw is there any way on setting the window position before or while the window being is created? I know there is `glfwSetWindowPos()` but I can only call this after the window is created and I get a flash change in position, I'm looking for something similar to glut's `glutInitWindowPosition()` function which is called just before the window is created, so that the window is instantiated at the given position without having to move anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hidden window (`GLFW_VISIBLE`), change the position ([`glfwSetWindowPos`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga1abb6d690e8c88e0c8cd1751356dbca8)) and show the window ([`glfwShowWindow`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga61be47917b72536a148300f46494fc66)). For instance:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "my window", NULL, NULL);
glfwSetWindowPos(window, 100, 100);
glfwShowWindow(window);
```